# Writing a c program to attach a prefix to a list of strings entered

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm  kind of new to C programming and I'm writing a program to attach a prefix to a list of strings entered by a user.
here's a snippet of code.

```
char names[5][20], prefix[5];
int i=0;
// accept 5 names and a prefix
printf("Please enter the 5 names and a prefix\n");
for(i;i<=4;i++ )
{
    printf("Enter name %d\n ",i+1);
    scanf("%s", &names[i]);

}
printf("prefix: \n ");
scanf("%s", &prefix);
printf("\n\n\n");


for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    strcat(prefix,names[i]);

    printf("%s\n", prefix);
}
```

My problem is that instead of  adding the prefix to the next string entered it's just listing them all.

Here's what I mean:

```
Please enter the 5 names and a prefix
Enter name 1
 i
Enter name 2
 c
Enter name 3
 h
Enter name 4
 a
Enter name 5
 e
prefix:
 m



mi
mic
mich
micha
michae
```

Comment: `strcat()` does not work that way.

Comment: The `cat` in `strcat()` stands more for a "copy to the end of" instead a "concatenate to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `prefix` has five elements. The sub-arrays in `names` have 20 elements.

Even if each string is only one character long, that will be a string of six character (not including the string zero terminator, which makes it seven). That will not fit into an array of five characters.

You need to increase the length of `prefix` by quite a bit.

It is also not doing what you want, since that's not how `strcat` work.

If you just want to *print* the strings with the prefix, then do that:

```
printf("%s%s\n", prefix, names[i]);
```

If you want to actually add a prefix to a string for later usage, then I suggest using a second array for the prefixed strings:

```
char prefixed_names[5][25];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    strcpy(prefixed_names[i], prefix);  // Copy the prefix to the new string
    strcat(prefixed_names[i], names[i]);  // Append the name
}
```

Comment: Looks better now.

Comment: Can you use `strcpy()` without initializing the array in any way first? I remember having read that you should first do something like `chararray[0] = 0`, so that we can be sure there isn't any garbage in there and the string is properly recognized as being an empty string. Maybe I got something wrong though?

Comment: @domsson The `strcpy` function just overwrites whatever is already in the destination. It doesn't need the destination to be initialized in any way. The `strcat` function on the other hand needs a zero-terminated string to be in the destination.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's good to know, thank you for clearing it up for me!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you would achieve:

```
char names[5][20], prefix[5];
char tmp[32];
int i=0;
// accept 5 names and a prefix
printf("Please enter the 5 names and a prefix\n");
for(i;i<=4;i++)
   {
    printf("Enter name %d\n ",i+1);
    scanf("%s", &names[i]);
   }
printf("prefix: \n ");
scanf("%s", &prefix);
printf("\n\n\n");

for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
   {
    strcpy(tmp, prefix);
    strcat(tmp, names[i]);
    printf("%s\n", tmp);
   }
```

The problem is that you are concatenating all the string in the same container `prefix`.